# Assembly writing to stdout

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I'm trying to write 4 bytes to the screen using:

```
nasm -f elf -g ****.asm
```

Nothing is happening.

Here is the relevant code segment:

```
mov     eax, 4             ; ow print error mesg
mov     ebx, 1
mov     ecx, DWORD [para]
mov     edx, 4
int     080h
```

This is my debug run of that portion of my code.  Nothing is being printed, I'm showing you the contents of `$ecx` via gdb.

```
253             mov     eax, 4             ; ow print error mesg
(gdb)
254             mov     ebx, 1
(gdb)
255             mov     ecx, DWORD [para]
(gdb)
256             mov     edx, 4
(gdb)
257             int     080h
(gdb) p /t $ecx
$1 = 1100001010101001000010110000010
(gdb) step
```

No idea what I'm doing wrong.  From previous posts here and on other websites, I can't see a discrepancy with the accepted method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the normal value of para ?

I have an old code and I don't use DWORD
just

```
mov     ecx, [para]
```

Comment: How is `para` defined? I think that you need to pass a pointer only: `mov ecx,foo` and`foo` is define as following e.g., `foo db "etc"` it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

`ecx` wants the address of the text to print. Unless `para` is a "pointer" (holds the address of the text), just `mov ecx, para` is probably correct. Strictly speaking, `ebx` might want to be 2 (stderr), but I doubt if that's your problem. Show us `para`!